# Extract from specific key in a NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

The following code saves a value to a number of NSUserDefaults where the filenames are generated from a string stored in a .plist (eg. 'storedbook1', 'storedbook2' where the strings stored in the .plist are 'book1', 'book2' etc.). However, I only want to target one NSUserDefault at a time. How can I amend the code to be specific? (eg. If I wanted give 'storedbook20' the value of 3).

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myListPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"books.plist"];
tableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myListPath];

for (NSDictionary* dict in tableData) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stored%@", dict[@"filename"]];
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey: key];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Sample .plist

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>title1</string>
        <key>filename</key>
        <string>book1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>title2</string>
        <key>filename</key>
        <string>book2</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Using the following code show that both storedbook1 and storedbook2 have the value of 5 added when I only want to add the value of 5 to one at a time (there's a lot more than two items in the real .plist):

```
NSNumber *checkednew = 0;
checkednew = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey: key];
int checknew = [checkednew intValue];

NSLog(@"%@", key);
NSLog(@"%d", checknew);
```

The output for key is:

storedbook1
5
storedbook2
5

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: *"targeting all off the items when I only want to target one at a time"*. I'm also not sure how this is working `dict[@"check"]` since you don't have the key `"check"` in your Sample `.plist`.

Comment: You need to provide more information

Comment: I've corrected the code to reflect the 'key' that creates the filename.

Comment: Can you explain why you're looping through an array if you only want to set the value for a single key? And should your code read `dict[@"filename"]` rather than `dict[@"check"]`?

Comment: Maybe that's where I'm going wrong? I've corrected the code above.

Comment: So how do I alter this so I only set the value for a single key?

Answer (score 0):

They are values no keys so If you want to no values are repeat you can use a global cont property and add +1 when you add a new object to your NSUserDefaults like this

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in tableData) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stored%@", dict[@"check"]];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cont] forKey: key];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
        cont++;

        ...
}
```

For control your number you could to save this number in your NSUserDefaults after save it

```
[standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cont] forKey: @"ContValues"];
```

Comment: I've probably worded my question really badly. As it stands all of the NSUserDefaults are given a value of 5 (eg. storedbook1 through to storedbook100 all get given a value of 5). What I want to do is target only one storedbookx depending on choices by the user, but controlled programatically, so I might want to put a value of 3 for storedbook20, and then later a value of 7 for storedbook36, for example.

Comment: then or you do a loop over all your NSUserDefaults properties searching your value (depends of how much properties you will save its a right choice) or if you have CoreData or other database you could save which values you saved

Comment: I don't think my question is clear or I haven't explained enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the plist file store the obtained key names into a dictionary ( instead of saving in NSUserDefaults). And when ever you receive a user action get your key name (storedbookx) from that dictionary and save the value to NSUserDefaults. This will save numerous i/o and iteration operations.